# Jquery .Each function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a column to my table. My js code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

     jQuery('#addCol').click(function () {

        var countRows = $('#blacklistgrid tr').length;

        $('.class').each(function() {
            $( this ).append("<td><input type=\"text\"/></td>");
        });
    });
```

This code can be found in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xz180q4/). What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong element.

You should do this:

```
jQuery('.Row').each(function() {
      jQuery( this ).append("<td><input type=\"text\"/></td>");
});
```

Notice `jQuery('.Row')` instead of `jQuery('.class')`

See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), the class selector is used like `jQuery('.<classname>')`, and in this case you want to get each rows, which are identified by `Row` class